# binary sudoku in swi prolog

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog, sudoku, clpfd

As a prolog newbie, I wanted to try to implement a binary sudoku solver.(Code is below, swi-prolog). Binary sudoku is explained here : https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/16982/how-hard-is-binary-sudoku-puzzle

However, when performing the following query :

```
binarySudoku([[1,0],[0,1]]). I get "true."
binarySudoku([[1,_],[_,_]]). I get "false."
```

Now obviously it shouldn't return false as there is a solution... Why is this happening/how can I fix this?

```
:-use_module(library(clpfd)).

validRow(Row) :-
    Row ins 0..1,
    length(Row,L),
    sum(Row,#=,L/2).

matrixNth(Matr,X,Y,El) :-
    nth1(Y,Matr,CurRow),
    nth1(X,CurRow,El).

allDifferent([]).
allDifferent([X|Y]) :-
    not(member(X,Y)),
    allDifferent(Y).


invalid(Rows,X,Y) :-
    AboveY is Y-1,
    BelowY is Y+1,
    matrixNth(Rows,X,Y,1),
    matrixNth(Rows,X,AboveY,1),
    matrixNth(Rows,X,BelowY,1).
invalid(Rows,X,Y) :-
    LeftX is X-1,
    RightX is X+1,
    matrixNth(Rows,X,Y,1),
    matrixNth(Rows,LeftX,Y,1),
    matrixNth(Rows,RightX,Y,1).

binarySudoku(Rows) :-
    length(Rows,Height),
    transpose(Rows,Cols),
    length(Cols,Height),
    maplist(validRow,Rows),
    foreach(between(1,Height,X),foreach(between(1,Height,Y),not(invalid(Rows,X,Y)))),
    allDifferent(Rows).
```

Comment: label(Row) does seem to fix it but why does that work? in the example sudoku solver in the clpfd manual there is never a call to label made (maybe implicit in all_distinct?)

Comment: I wouldn't call it a latin square because not only has it different constraints, when you go to bigger widths, it doesn't even closely resemble one...
Also, typing "binary sudoku" into google finds the same puzzle I am describing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of `(\+)/1`, which is not logically sound in this case, use the pure constraint `dif/2`: Your code works as expected of you change the line `not(member(X,Y))` to:

`maplist(dif(X), Y)`

Example query (notice that I also use a_more_readable_naming_convention insteadOfMixingTheCases):

```
?- binary_sudoku([[1,A],[B,C]]), label([A,B,C]).
A = B, B = 0,
C = 1 ;
false.
```

+1 for using CLP(FD), which is a good fit for this task.

Comment: Hehe, not only did you explain why prolog is doing this, you also provided a fix that made it work as expected :)
I also went ahead and changed not(invalid) to valid.

Now when I give it a larger puzzle (12X12) it runs out of global stack. Is this the limit of my simple algorithm or is there a quick fix I don't see?

Comment: Please show the new code, possibly in a new question because this is now a different issue.